# Charles proxy not working with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, charles-proxy

I am working on Mac and have identical Proxy settings for the System and Firefox browser. However,  I am able to see my Firefox traffic in Chrales but I don't see my Chrome and Safari traffic (which use System Proxy Settings). What do I need to do? How can I check the debug this?

Already restarted my browser but it didn't help. I have set and reset proxy settings, but of no use.

One thing to note: I am on a VPN although I don't think this should affect Chrome as Firefox is going through the proxy.

Comment: Which is the host and which is the port ?

Comment: I am using localhost 8888. This is configured in Charles, System Settings and Firefox. Firefox and Charles are working but Chrome and Safari don't go through the proxy.

Comment: It seems ok ... I suppose that your problem is related to your protocol. Try to focus on this. When you choose a proxy from `Internet Options > LAN Settings`, click on `Advanced` to add that proxy for every protocol.

Comment: Actually, it is something else. As soon as I leave the VPN, then Charles starts picking up traffic from Chrome. I don't know how can I keep the VPN and also make Chrome work with Charles.

Answer (score 97):

For anyone else using VPN: Charles must be turned on before VPN. So quitting VPN after turning on Charles won't work either.

Also in my case VPN can't be turned on at all.

Comment: This has hung me up several times, thinking that I need to restart. In my case, disconnecting from VPN and reconnecting instantly started showing traffic in Charles. Also the [Ruchira Randana] answer about enabling and also enabling on startup, the Mac OS X Proxy is key.

Comment: You can just e.g. turn off wifi or unplug ethernet physically - no need to stop VPN app. That would be enough

Comment: This was the issue in my case. Thanks!

Comment: The number of times I restarted my PC... Thanks mate

Answer (score 34):

Did you enable "Proxy-> Mac OS X Proxy"?

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Quit your VPN! I was confused almost one year and really upset, i cannot record on my mac.But today i quit my vpn(xx-net) it does works.

Comment: This was my problem! I had Tunelblick running, and even tho no connection was made through it, it still did not allow Charles to work properly.

Comment: in additon: if you use a chrome proxy plugin, you'd better set it to the mode: global proxy

Comment: first you should turn off all your vpn, i.e. shadowsocks and your browser proxy plugin. Second you turn on charles. This does work well for me.

Comment: I turned off my VPN and it started working too. I turned my VPN back on Charles still records traffic. I wonder if there's a workaround that involves messing around with the routing tables.

Answer (score 6):

Just got caught out with this - the Hola VPN Chrome extension was managing Chrome's proxy settings so it wasn't using the system proxy.

Simply disabling the Hola extension got it working for me again.

Comment: Just to note: don't just simply disable the browser plugin, but quit from the whole windows program.

Answer (score 2):

I turn off a chrome proxy plugin and it works!

Comment: Yes, the use of any extension that takes over proxy configuration seems to be an issue. Disable (or remove) the proxy controlling extension and everything seems to go back through the normal MacOS proxy configuration.

Comment: When you have the `Proxy SwitchyOmega` Chrome extension installed: 
Select `System Proxy` (instead of `Direct` or some other proxy), and Charles should be used instead. Also check the `Bypass List` in the `SwitchyOmega Options`!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extension '[SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif)' can solve the "VPN and Charles cannot turn on at the same time" issue by configure the auto switch option:

1. Add Charles mode
   [image: Charles config]
2. Add VPN mode
   [image: VPN Configuration]
3. auto switch configuration
   [image: auto switch config]
4. Use auto switch mode in Chrome
   [image: Use auto switch mode]

Answer (score 1):

Desktop applications that set system-wide proxy don't work really well with VPN. I struggled with Charles & Fiddler because I was under a VPN network and almost all the time I couldn't use any of the apps while on my company VPN So I googled for Web Proxy chrome extension and found [Requestly](https://requestly.io).

I am using the [Requestly Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-url-modify-heade/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) and the chrome extension works well with VPN and it has all the features that Charles has.