# Charles can't see HTTP requests with VPN opened on IOS

Tags: debugging, proxy, request, vpn, charles-proxy

I have a VPN (BIG-IP Edge) connection on which I wanted to test some websites using Charles Web Debugging Proxy, but Charles doesn't seem to detect my VPN connection because it doesn't detect the websites that I'm running on the VPN network.
Things I have tried so far:

1. Running Charles before establishing the VPN connection as mentioned here: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/vpn-not-working-with-charles/
2. Enabling/Disabling “Proxy>macOS Proxy”
3. Disabling “Auto Proxy Config” in system preferences as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942498/charles-web-debugging-proxy-not-detecting-vpn-connection)
4. Restarted system/Charles and Simulator, always simulator after charles.

Note: VPN does not even connect if I enable  “Proxy>macOS Proxy” in Charles